# Possible to create object from reflection of a class in memory?

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, reflection, introspection

I have a program that I'm writing, where I'm attempting to take an encrypted class file, decrypt it while loading into memory(not decrypting it on the drive), and execute parts of the class. I'm able to do this with static methods, however, I'd like to find out if it's possible to do this

I also wanted to just specify, I am not writing anything malicious. I'm actually doing this as an attempt to understand reflection, and possibly using it as a form of source code protection. Payload just seemed like a gratifying name for my proof of concept.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter password:");
    String pass = scan.nextLine();

    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    byte[] keyBytes = md5.digest(pass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);


    InputStream in = Master.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Payload\\ENC\\Payload.class");

    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        boas.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    byte[] encrypted = boas.toByteArray();


    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        PayloadLoader loader = new PayloadLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), decrypted);
        Class<?> c = loader.loadClass("Payload.Payload");

        Method main = c.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        main.invoke(null, (Object) args);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
    }
```

Above is where it is loaded into memory and executed. Instead of invoking a Main method however, I'd like to create an instance of this thread, and start it. Below is the basic thread itself

```
private Thread t;
private String threadName;

Payload(String name){
    threadName = name;
    if(config.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("Creating Thread - " + threadName);
}

public void setName(String name){
    threadName = name;
}

public void run()
{
    if(config.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("Running Thread - " + threadName);


}

public void start()
{
    if(config.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("Starting Thread - " + threadName);

    if(t == null)
    {
        t = new Thread (this, threadName);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

My question is, would it be possible to create this object, and start the thread itself? This is the main thing I'm trying to accomplish, as I hope to have this multithreaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Class` class has `getConstructors` method you can use:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object payload = constructor.newInstance("ThreadName");
((PayloadStarter) payload).start();
```

The `Payload` class will also need to implement a shared interface that is in the classpath of the code in order to cast and invoke the `start` method. I have used a ficticious `PayloadStarter` in the example above

Comment: Payload isn't being recognized as an object type, when setting the constructor type. I feel like I have to reflect reference it, and I'm unsure of how to do that. But this has gotten me so much further. Any idea how to get it to reference the payload class in the constructor type?

Comment: @Kristoff You can create the object, but you can't use the class name as a type in the source text unless it is going to be present on the original CLASSPATH. You need to refer to the object via some type that *is* available, e.g. Runnable, Task, etc.

Comment: @EJP, nice one, didn't spot that.

Comment: The only problem is, I'm still getting this... 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Payload.Payload.<init>(java.lang.String)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at Payload.Master.main(Master.java:61)

Comment: Yeah, the exception above is being thrown when attempting to create the constructor object. I have been doing research, and tried a few things, such as using a default constructor, yet, it still gets thrown.

Comment: Looks like the constructor is package visible in your example. Have you tried making it public?

Comment: Yeah, it's public. All of my classes at the moment are. I'm currently trying to grab as much information from the class as I can, such as displaying the class info, method info, parameters, etc.

The type of data I'm getting is below (Shortened). Yet, I still get that NoSuchMethodException when it tries to instantiate the object. I feel like it's trying to access the methods from somewhere it shouldn't be. 


Loaded: Payload.Payload
Method Found: run
Method Found: start
Method Found: setName
Method Found: wait
Method Found: wait
Method Found: equals
Method Found: toString

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72533/discussion-between-kristoff-and-anuj-shah).